# How to put html canvas in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, center

I have used `<div style="text-align:center;">` to align my canvas to the middle of the screen horizontally but the y axis is not changed whatsoever, I want the HTML canvas to be in the middle of the x and y-axis.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Note to self: dont use margin 0px

Comment: Please consider editing the question and adding your code, so we can understand the issue in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, but not always obvious/intuitive ways to center an element vertically on a page.

Here's one example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```